# Linking error references

Tags: ios

I was trying to update a framework that we used before, since they had completely renewed it, there wasn't just a simple way of updating the files.

In my project I just removed the current framework and added the newer one.
After some testing I wanted to go back to the old version, so I removed the new framework and added the old one again. So basically nothing changed in the code or in the files.

But still, when I try to build my files now, I'm getting this linking error, again, no changes to the code were made.

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DocumentViewController.thumbPage in /Users/wouter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WiC-dubdfuwbsdrffuatbuonqmpzuvcz/Build/Intermediates/WiC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WiC.build/Objects-normal/i386/DocumentViewController-B98A1B42C236E973.o and /Users/wouter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WiC-dubdfuwbsdrffuatbuonqmpzuvcz/Build/Intermediates/WiC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WiC.build/Objects-normal/i386/DocumentViewController-B98A1B42C236E973.o for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Why would it give me this error if everything is the same as before?
My guess is that Xcode keeps some references (even though I asked to delete them) to deleted files.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my "Compile Sources" was keeping a references to the same file previously deleted, trying to delete it didn't help.
After doing a Clean and Clean build folder the problem was magically fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're at the same revision? Can you back out to that version with git?

So you're project is finding at least 2 copies of ivar DocumentViewController.thumbPage ... Did you:

1. Do a Clean All
2. Delete the build directory

If that doesn't work, I would search the project or the project.pbxproj file (just using a text editor) and seeing if you can find the object or 2 frameworks that would be added to your target that contains this.

If that doesn't work, blow away the .xcodeproj directory and just created a new one and add all your files to it ... but this is as last resort.

Comment: The Clean en Clean build folder sure helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that you accidentally #imported a .m file instead of a .h file.  Check to make sure that your #import reads

```
#import DocumentViewController.h
```

Do a clean and run again.

Comment: It says DocumentViewController.h, everything worked perfectly before, until trying out the other framework.

Comment: Press shift+cmd+f and search for'.m"' (without the single quotes, but include that last double quote)

Comment: what about checking your 'Compile Sources' list.  Does it contain two versions of the DocumentViewController.m file?

Comment: It did contain only one reference there, I tried deleting it but for some reason it didn't let me, after pressing delete a couple of times, I did a Clean and Clean Build Folder and everything worked again ...

Comment: Well then, if that is the answer, post it and accept your own answer so this doesnt wind up in the 'Not Answered" tab.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!